# Как сделать вращение Rotate через отклик мыши?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-event

Есть вывод цифр через пейнт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace exam399
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

        const double Degrees = 5;  
        Font font;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            font = new Font("Arial",15);
            this.ResizeRedraw = true; 
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
            StringFormat strfmt = new StringFormat();
            strfmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            gr.TranslateTransform(Size.Width / 2, Size.Height / 2);


            for (double i = 0; i < 359; i += Degrees)
            {

                GraphicsState gr1 = gr.Save();
                gr.RotateTransform((float)i);
                gr.TranslateTransform(150, 0);
                gr.DrawString(7.ToString(), font, Brushes.Blue,
                0, 0, strfmt);
                gr.Restore(gr1);

                GraphicsState gr2 = gr.Save();
                gr.RotateTransform((float)i);
                gr.TranslateTransform(-50, 0);
                gr.DrawString(1.ToString(), font, Brushes.Blue,
                0, 0, strfmt);
                gr.Restore(gr2);

            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Как сделать чтобы они вращались по часовой? Отклики на Mouse_Click() и Винапи не понял.

Предположительный мой псевдо-код.

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnMouseClick(e);
   int rol=0;
   Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
   gr.RotateTransform((float)rol+=10);
   if(rol>359)
   {
      rol=0;
   }
   Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: не очень понятно, на какие именно действия мышью, как именно должна происходить реакция?

Comment: @4per на 1 клик левой кнопки мыши, рисунок выше должен вращаться на определённое кол-во градусов по часовой стрелке.

Comment: @4per ещё не сделал ваши правки, но при моём варианте ругается на  строчку Graphics gr = e.Graphics;

Comment: @4per если вы поняли. как мне точно помочь, то будьте добры дать ответ и с примером. Коментарии не то место)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в класс формы поле:

```
int start = 0;
```

В обработчике события `Paint` измените цикл:

```
for (double i = start; i < start + 359; i += Degrees)
```

В обработчике события `MouseClick` напишите:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    start++;
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Теперь при каждом клике на форме ваш рисунок будет слегка поворачиваться.

Хотя, конечно, такой способ рисования очень неэффективен.

---

Чтобы рисунок постоянно вертелся, используем таймер. Таймеров в .NET несколько разных, мы используем из пространства имён `System.Windows.Forms`.

Добавляем поле формы:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
```

В событии таймера `Tick` пишем:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start++;
    this.Refresh();
}
```

В событии `MouseClick` запускаем или останавливаем таймер:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
}
```

При необходимости задаём нужный интервал тика таймера:

```
timer.Interval = 50;
```

Чтобы не было жуткого мерцания при перерисовке, нужно задать двойную буферизацию:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл где обратиться через форму к клику Form1_MouseClick. Кинул вместо этого на кнопку отклик и выглядит круто,но цифры при сдвиге съедаются. Скрин. http://floomby.ru/s2/KgVe5R/full/

Comment: Form1_MouseClick найден, но проблема со съедание цифр не исчезла, так и задумано?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer - в цикле `for` переменная `start` два раза.

Comment: @Aleander оу, я уже заметил. Добавив свою переменную end.

Comment: ещё вопрос. А как можно сделать, чтобы при клике он постоянно вертелся и мы можем выставить лишь start++? Я к тому что при любом другом значении,например start+=10; движения не заметны и они смещаются покрывая те же места на которых были.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer - см. обновление ответа.

Comment: отклик тика тоже в свойствах формы находится? Не нашёл. Или просто пишем.?)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer - на будущее: одна тема - один вопрос. Если поместили таймер на форму в дизайнере из Toolbox, то событие тик можно сгенерировать двойным кликом, как любые другие. Если вручную написали код, то в конструкторе формы добавьте `timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;`